# Google Cloud SQL - Can't create new tempfile

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, temporary-files

I'm trying to repair a table and get the error "can't create new tempfile". The old table was roughly 7gb. Total DB sitting at 17gb right now.

I connected to mysql via SSH and ran df -h and nothing happens, not sure google cloud sql allows this.

Any ideas?

I've also noticed that my tables are always in need of repair when i ran this same application on a VPS it had way better performance. Does anyone else experience worse performance on Google cloud vs traditional VPS?

Comment: chances are that your tmpdir is pointing to a destination that is not large enough to repair a 7gb table...You can do a `show variables like 'tmpdir'` to see where its pointing...You can change it in the my.cnf to point to a larger directory (such as the data dir) and then restart mysql...should be good then to repair table

Comment: i can't acces my.cnf from google cloud sql?

Comment: The limit for tempfiles in Cloud SQL is 10GBs; repairing the table used up that much (that's the jump from 7GB -> 17GB). Unfortunately, that 10GB limit is not configurable; it's a hard limitation on our architecture. Your only real option here is to revert to an older backup :( Repairing only makes sense for MyISAM tables, and we strongly strongly recommend you only use InnoDB tables, so maybe consider modifying your schema.

Comment: What kind of applications is this? How many writes per a second to the table? I am not familiar with google-cloud-sql but one approach maybe to export the 7g table, repair it on another mysql server that you do have more control over and then re-import the table back but depending on the application this may not be possible. You should be using InnoDB tables and steer clear of MyISAM...

Comment: @cflewis MyISAM to InnoDB is an alter table...OP would run into same issue if he tried at this point to convert the table schema...U guys should really look into that hard limitation cause it would seem one would run into such an issue if they try to alter, repair, optimize etc any table larger than ~5G on your hardware...serious setback...

Comment: @cflewis thanks for the reply, i suppose i'll use restore but since i get frequent table crashes doesn't seem as efficient as just running mysql off a compute engine vm

Comment: @BK435: We know it's painful, but it's very difficult to fix based on the infrastructure available to us. We are working on it. And yeah, I realize an ALTER TABLE with the data here would have the same effect, but if the data can be exported and reimported with InnoDB specified in the schema instead, that would work.

Comment: @BarryDeen: We don't expect users to get frequent table crashes, at least not if they are using InnoDB. As I suspect you are using MyISAM, perhaps you could tell me the use case you have for it? We would ideally like all our users to move to InnoDB and want to make sure we get rid of any roadblocks to that.

Comment: @cflewis, that is why I was asking the OP about his application...is it mission critical, is this app 24x7, how many writes per a second to the table....however, if all these answers were yes, given your architecture, OP cannot do the aforementioned export-fix-reimport table...

Comment: @BarryDeen, given the size of the table, I would suggest moving off this platform to something that can accommodate a table size that large...if you have to make any future changes, such as alter table, including creating an index, you will run into same issue...

Comment: Managed to alter to innodb but performance is literally 10x worse on my writes. My app writes about 10,000 rows / hour on MyISAM and only does 1,200 rows / hour on InnoDB...

Comment: I think i'm just going to spin up a VM instead of using cloud sql...